# Unable to translate a comment on user Rate Limit History

Tags: bug, status-review, moderator-tools, localization, rate-limiting

The autogenerated comment on user Rate Limit History (История ограничения рейтинга) like the following one is [not ready](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=blocked%20from%20asking%20questions) to translation:

> [image]

> User Id {id} is blocked from asking questions for {days} days on {sitename}

There are possibly other related comments, but it's hard to find them since looking on many profiles is needed.